# Even after rolling back to Xcode 13.3.1 I can no longer debug apps on my iPhone with iOS 15.6

Tags: xcode

After my iPhone 13 updated to iOS 15.6, Xcode 13.4.1 no longer was able to debug apps on the device. Many posts and Xcode support recommend that I roll back to Xcode 13.3.1.

So I renamed Xcode to "Xcode 13.4.1", downloaded the xip for 13.3.1 and also confirmed that I am running the previous version, via the About menu.

Yet I still get the following error:

> Failed to prepare device for development. This operation can fail if
> the version of the OS on the device is incompatible with the installed
> version of Xcode. You may also need to restart your mac and device in
> order to correctly detect compatibility.

I have cleaned the build folder, I also downloaded the 15.5 image, renamed it to 15.6, and placed it in the DeviceSupport folder. But it nothing has worked.

I don't know if Xcode uses any config files that I need to clean, or anything else I can't think of. Has anyone been through this?

Answer (score 1):

[Xcode 13.4](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-13_4-release-notes) ([build 13F100](https://xcodereleases.com/)) has a known issue preparing devices running iOS 15.6 beta and is not officially supported. The fix is to wait for a newer build of 13.4.x Xcode.

Anecdotally some have said it works after disconnecting the phone and restarting both the phone and the Mac.

There are two workarounds:

- The official workaround from Apple is to install Xcode 13.3.1. You have tried this. The majority of the config files are inside the Xcode directory. You can download AppCleaner and have it show you everything it would delete if you allowed it to uninstall Xcode. For me that list was 11 GB and 39 files.[image: appclean] I'd exam those files and possibly make copies of anything outside /Applications/Xcode.app before allowing it to remove.
- Navigate to
  `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/` and duplicate the `15.5` folder with a new name of `15.6`. If this works, it is much safer.